# how to parse a field containing different unicode string with logstash

Tags: unicode, logstash, gsub

I used logstash jdbc statement 
"select utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(dbms_lob.substr(field,length(field))) from table;" 
to fetch blob field. output in logstash is with unicode charaters like "\v\u0004\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0001\u0005\u0001\u0004\u0019\u0000c\u0000o\u0000m\u0000.\u0000w\u0000m\u0000.\u0000d\u0000a\u0000t\u0000a\u0000.\u0000I\u0000S\u0000M\u0000e\u0000m"' 
which actual value is "com.wm.data.ISMem"
I need to replace all the unicode characters and parse my data.
Anyone suggest how this can be resloved and which logstash filter can be used here to parse the SQL output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `gsub` from the `mutate` filter.

```
mutate {
    gsub ["field-name","\v\u0004\u0001\u0005\u0001\u0004\u0019",""]
    gsub ["field=name","\u0000",""]
}
```

The first one will remove `\v\u0004\u0001\u0005\u0001\u0004\u0019`, which seems to be some kind of header.

The second one will remove the remaining `\u0000` from your string.

Comment: can you suggest any regex pattern for this, the unicode pattern change for different logs

Answer (score 1):

You could mutate it using

```
    mutate {
        gsub => [
            "message", "[\\]u0000", "",
            "message", "[\\]v[\\]u0004[\\]u0001[\\]u0005[\\]u0001[\\]u0004[\\]u0019", ""]
    }
```

I would expect there is a way to fix the encoding in a ruby filter, but I do not know what it is.